# Add Webpart on right and bottom page

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

I'm building a SP site using an "Enterprise Search Center" template since i want to use the webpart section on the left side of the page.

However, i couldn't add a webpart section on the right and bottom part of my site as editing the default page layout is disabled.

Could you please help me to modify the default page layout or suggest me a different template which has a left, right and bottom section to add webparts ?

The ones that i tried do not allow me to add a webpart on the left side as that part is taken by quick launch.

I'm new to SP and any step by step instruction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to site settings->Look and Feel-> Page layouts and site templates->select “Pages in this site can use any layout” under Page Layouts section. Check if you can select Layout in the ribbon.
[image]

Comment: Hi Hellofiona_MSFT, thank you for your reply but unfortunately that didn't help. I added and tried all the page layouts but i couldn't find a page layout which has a left, right and bottom webpart section.

Comment: Which page did you edit?  Go to Pages library and create a new page, create a new page, check if you can select the page layout when creating.